# Drawing line dynamically on google Map on location changing

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing an application on google map and want to draw a line from current location to a selected point i have tried a lot but when i select a point it does not draw a line between current point and my selected point instead it draws line on a road near to selected points. My code is given below

```
   @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng latlon) 
    {           
        this.latlng = null;
        this.latlng = latlon;
        makePath(this.latlng);
    }
    private void makePath(LatLng latlon)
    {
         if(markerPoints.size()>1)
          {
                markerPoints.clear();
                gMap.clear();
                isSecondPoint = false;
                markerPoints.add(origin);
                options.position(origin);
          }
          if(markerPoints.size()>1)
          {
                markerPoints.clear();
                gMap.clear();
                isSecondPoint = false;
                markerPoints.add(origin);
                options.position(origin);
          }

          if(!isSecondPoint)
          {
            markerPoints.add(latlon);
            options.position(latlon);
            isSecondPoint = true;
            editSecond.putFloat("latitude", (float)latlon.latitude);
            editSecond.putFloat("longitude", (float)latlon.longitude);
            editSecond.commit();
            if(!isFirstPoint)
            {
                origin = markerPoints.get(0);
                options.position(origin);
                   gMap.addMarker(options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker3)));
            }
            gMap.addMarker(options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker3)));
            gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlon));
          }
          if(markerPoints.size() >= 2)
          {
             prevTime = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000L;

             dest = markerPoints.get(1);  

             staticRouteTask = new RouteTask();
             staticRouteTask.execute();  
          }
   }
 private class RouteTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
 {
        String response = "";
        private RouteTask() {}

        protected String doInBackground(String... urls)
        {
             document = v2GetRouteDirection.getDocument(origin, dest, MapRouteDirection.MODE_WALKING);
             response = "Success";
             return response;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
             //gMap.clear();
             if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("Success"))
             {
                 ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint = v2GetRouteDirection.getDirection(document);
                 PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(10).color(Color.YELLOW);

                 for (int i = 0; i < directionPoint.size(); i++) 
                 {
                       rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(i));
                 }
                 // Adding route on the map
                 gMap.addPolyline(rectLine);
                 MarkerOptions m = new MarkerOptions();
                 m.position(dest);
                 m.draggable(true);
                 gMap.addMarker(m);
                 m = null;
             }

        }
```

}

public class MapRouteDirection {

```
 public final static String MODE_DRIVING = "driving";
    public final static String MODE_WALKING = "walking";

    public MapRouteDirection() { }

    public Document getDocument(LatLng start, LatLng end, String mode) {
         // Origin of route
        String str_origin = "origin="+start.latitude+","+start.longitude;

        // Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination="+end.latitude+","+end.longitude;

        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";

        //Traveling mode
        mode = "mode=walking";

        //Units setting
        String units = "units=metric";

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor+"&"+units+"&"+mode;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;

    /*    String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?"
                + "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude 
                + "&destination=" + end.latitude + "," + end.longitude
                + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving";*/
        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(in);
            return doc;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getDurationText (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
        Log.i("DurationText", node2.getTextContent());
        return node2.getTextContent();
    }

    public int getDurationValue (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
        Log.i("DurationValue", node2.getTextContent());
        return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
    }

    public String getDistanceText (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
        Log.i("DistanceText", node2.getTextContent());
        return node2.getTextContent();
    }

    public int getDistanceValue (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
        Log.i("DistanceValue", node2.getTextContent());
        return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
    }

    public String getStartAddress (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("start_address");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        Log.i("StartAddress", node1.getTextContent());
        return node1.getTextContent();
    }

    public String getEndAddress (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("end_address");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        Log.i("StartAddress", node1.getTextContent());
        return node1.getTextContent();
    }

    public String getCopyRights (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("copyrights");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        Log.i("CopyRights", node1.getTextContent());
        return node1.getTextContent();
    }

    public ArrayList<LatLng> getDirection (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1, nl2, nl3;
        ArrayList<LatLng> listGeopoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("step");
        if (nl1.getLength() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < nl1.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
                nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();

                Node locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "start_location"));
                nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                Node latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
                Node lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
                listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));

                locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "polyline"));
                nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "points"));
                ArrayList<LatLng> arr = decodePoly(latNode.getTextContent());
                for(int j = 0 ; j < arr.size() ; j++) {
                    listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(arr.get(j).latitude, arr.get(j).longitude));
                }

                locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "end_location"));
                nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
                lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
                lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
                lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
                listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
            }
        }

        return listGeopoints;
    }

    private int getNodeIndex(NodeList nl, String nodename) {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < nl.getLength() ; i++) {
            if(nl.item(i).getNodeName().equals(nodename))
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private ArrayList<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;
        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;
            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng position = new LatLng((double) lat / 1E5, (double) lng / 1E5);
            poly.add(position);
        }
        return poly;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a line between the starting point and the ending point, you just need to add 2 LatLng to your polyline.

So instead of

```
for (int i = 0; i < directionPoint.size(); i++) 
{
 rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(i));
}
// Adding route on the map                
gMap.addPolyline(rectLine);
```

You can just use the first and the last LatLng like:

```
rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(0), directionPoint.get(directionPoint.size - 1);
gMap.addPolyline(rectLine);
```

The documentation of the [Polyline](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline) give this example:

```
Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
     .add(new LatLng(51.5, -0.1), new LatLng(40.7, -74.0))
     .width(5)
     .color(Color.RED));
```